# Terminate non-daemon python background Process when Program completes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a class that generates an indefinite amount of data objects. This class has a subprocess for this generation of data. Since this subprocess needs to use a pool of workers, it is non daemonic. Now the problem is that this Process will never finish it's work (because that is what it is designed to do), so when the main process finishes it will be unable to join and thus python will never quit. I therefore have to somehow terminate it reliably at the end of main. This has proven to be more tricky than I expected, because I cannot rely on the destructor of the class AND python processes have per default not timeout on their join method. A hacky workaround was to implement a cleanup function that is called at the very end and terminates the worker but that is obviously not a good solution since one could easily forget to call it. DO you have any suggestions how else this may be solved?
Regards,
Fabian

Here is a minimalistic example:

```
from builtins import range
from builtins import object
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Pool
from collections import deque


def transform(x):
    return x / 10


class SomeName(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.was_started = False

    def start(self):
        print("started")

        def produce(target_queue, num_processes):
            print("producer started")
            ctr = 0
            pool = Pool(num_processes)
            results = deque()
            for i in range(num_processes):
                item = ctr
                ctr += 1
                results.append(pool.apply_async(transform, args=(item,)))
            while True:
                target_queue.put(results.popleft().get())
                item = ctr
                ctr += 1
                results.append(pool.apply_async(transform, args=(item,)))


        self.queue = Queue(4)
        self.process = Process(target=produce, args=(self.queue, 4))
        self.process.daemon = False
        self.process.start()

        self.was_started = True

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.was_started:
            self.start()
        return self.queue.get()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = SomeName()
    [print(next(a)) for _ in range(20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a hotkey for termination. Also consider registering the worker threads. Then have a on kill, stop all workers command.

If you are looking for a terminal solution to kill all threads, then give the threads a unique name which will make it easy to pick them up from command line and run kill on all of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer!
Using a hotkey is just as problematic as using a cleanup function. Killing processes after the program is finished is not good here as well. I will not be the only one using this code and therefore it has to run by itself and clean itself up properly as well :-/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is this:
(not sure whether that is too hacky though)

```
from builtins import range
from builtins import object
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Pool
from collections import deque


def transform(x):
    return x / 10


class ProcessTerminateOnJoin(Process):
    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self.terminate()
        super(ProcessTerminateOnJoin, self).join(0.01)

class SomeName(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.was_started = False

    def start(self):
        print("started")

        def produce(target_queue, num_processes):
            print("producer started")
            ctr = 0
            pool = Pool(num_processes)
            results = deque()
            for i in range(num_processes):
                item = ctr
                ctr += 1
                results.append(pool.apply_async(transform, args=(item,)))
            while True:
                target_queue.put(results.popleft().get())
                item = ctr
                ctr += 1
                results.append(pool.apply_async(transform, args=(item,)))


        self.queue = Queue(4)
        self.process = ProcessTerminateOnJoin(target=produce, args=(self.queue, 4))
        self.process.daemon = False
        self.process.start()

        self.was_started = True

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.was_started:
            self.start()
        return self.queue.get()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = SomeName()
    [print(next(a)) for _ in range(20)]
```